# How do I read byte Array from socket and convert it to Bitmap in android?

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, sockets, inputstream

I converted a Bitmap to byte Array and sent over TCPServer in Csharp and now I have to receive and convert to bitmap in android. But I can't find a way to read bytes in android.

Comment: Reading bytes is the simplest of all. Please show your receiving code.

Comment: Once you received all bytes you can use BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray().